# I answered my own question, shouldn't I get the points?

Tags: support, reputation, self-answer

Let's say that I posted a question and nobody bothered to reply to my post, and I answered my own question. Do I get the points for the question?

I'll make the question even simpler: why shouldn't I get the points for the following question? [How to add exception handling to SqlDataSource.UpdateCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372161/exception-handling-for-sqldatasource-updatecommand)

Comment: If someone upvotes the question or your answer you will.

Comment: Not a single expert bothered to post anything. You're saying that they had no interest in helping me, but now they're going to upvote?

Comment: Someone edited your answer, so why wouldn't someone see your question and answer and upvote them or one of them??

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau, so you're saying that someone editing my answer by eliminating a meta question is good enough? In other words, they can't help me but they can eliminate text where I try to make a point?

Comment: Hi there. I edited your answer because asking whether or not you would get "the points" was only noise and put it at risk of being downvoted. That was not a move against you.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, I know it's not, and I apologize if it sounded that way.

Comment: My point is very simple: nobody looked at my question, so why shouldn't I get the points for the answer? The answer's correct.

Comment: "nobody bothered to reply" is a misunderstanding of how help works here. No one owes you an answer, and people may have not answered for a variety of reasons. Suggesting it is down to laziness is not an appropriate way to approach a volunteer community.

Comment: @halfer, Please don't put words in my mouth. I'm assuming that's the reason, God only knows why nobody replied. Maybe it was difficult? Who knows?

Comment: But if I put effort into posting an answer to a question, why shouldn't I get the benefits of other posters who post an accepted answer? After all, it's a question and my answer will be the accepted answer.

Comment: I failed to mention that someone actually downvoted my question for no reason **after** I posted an answer. Oh well...

Comment: If you claim that people "cannot be bothered" you are explicitly saying that they were not willing to expend effort you deem sufficient. I think it is quite reasonable to say that you are implying readers who did not post an answer were/are too lazy for you. Perhaps you could change your wording, and take on board this critique?

Comment: Anyways, it doesn't matter anymore. The important thing is that I found a correct solution to a question that nobody else could/would answer. End of story.

Comment: @halfer, it doesn't matter anymore. The important thing is that I found a correct solution to a question that nobody else could/would answer. End of story.

Comment: @GEOCHET, it doesn't matter anymore. The important thing is that I found a correct solution to a question that nobody else could/would answer. End of story.

Comment: No, it does matter. That is what you fail to understand.

Comment: No, it does not. If it does matter, then why did someone downvote my other question AFTER I answered my own question and AFTER I posted this question? Are you seeing something in my other question that merits a downvote?

Comment: I just noticed, it's been downvoted 4 times AFTER I answered my own question and AFTER I posted this meta question. Can you explain that to me?

Comment: I could answer, but it's not important to me to do so.  However, just for your 'tude issue, I'll add another downvote.

Comment: Surprise, someone that downvotes my question simply because they don't like me.

Comment: "Can you explain that to me?" - "Perhaps all your arguing and begging for votes is why people are responding to you negatively." It would help if you stopped emoting and read what was being written to you.

Comment: I just find it amusing that you think I'm begging for your vote. On the other hand, I see you're another one that downvotes all my questions because you don't like me. That's great; more power to you. Join the club.

Comment: You clearly have it all figured out.

Answer (score 26):

If other people vote up your question and/or answer you will get points.

However, you don't get any points from accepting the answer - that would lead to people gaming the system by accepting their own answer even when other people have provided good answers.

Comment: That makes sense, but you didn't seem to read the part that says that "nobody bothered to reply to my post". Would you like me to post the link to see if other people provided good answers or even participated?

Comment: @user3605366 - I assumed you meant that you got no other answers - but voting is independent of answering so I'm now not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

If the question and answer are helpful, you will probably get enough up-votes so that the +17 for accepting your own answer doesn't weigh much anymore. (+2 as the asker and +15 as answerer)

It's ok that you don't get it, because it might mean abuse by other users to get reputation.

Comment: Don't forget the +15 that you won't get from having your answer accepted as well.